# insert into database using jpa , jboss7.1 . @OneToMany annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using Jboss7.1 and jpa , ejb
I want to insert data -with  OneToMany relationship- into my mysql database.

I have two entitys personne and voiture. I want to save a person in my database and  associate  voiture for him. The problem is that when i test my code (test), i find that there is a new `personne` added to my database and there is no `voiture` added in the table `voiture`

please can you help me .

code :

the entity personne

```
package com.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * The persistent class for the personne database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
public class Personne implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idpersonne;

private String nom;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Voiture
@OneToMany(mappedBy="personne")
private Set<Voiture> voitures;

public Personne() {
}

public Personne(String nom) {
    super();
    this.nom = nom;
}

public int getIdpersonne() {
    return this.idpersonne;
}

public void setIdpersonne(int idpersonne) {
    this.idpersonne = idpersonne;
}

public String getNom() {
    return this.nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public Set<Voiture> getVoitures() {
    return this.voitures;
}

public void setVoitures(Set<Voiture> voitures) {
    this.voitures = voitures;
}

}
```

entity voiture

```
package com.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the voiture database table.
 * 
*/
@Entity
public class Voiture implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private int idvoiture;

private String type;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Personne
@ManyToOne
private Personne personne;

public Voiture() {
}

public Voiture(String type) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
}

public int getIdvoiture() {
    return this.idvoiture;
}

public void setIdvoiture(int idvoiture) {
    this.idvoiture = idvoiture;
}

public String getType() {
    return this.type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Personne getPersonne() {
    return this.personne;
}

public void setPersonne(Personne personne) {
    this.personne = personne;
}

 }
```

this is the interface

```
 package com.DAO;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

import com.domain.Personne;

@Remote
public interface PersonneDAO {

public void save(Personne personne);
public String sayhello();
}
```

the implementation
     package com.DAO.Impl;

```
 import javax.ejb.Stateless;
 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
 import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

 import com.DAO.VoitureDAO;
 import com.domain.Voiture;
 @Stateless
 public class VoitureDAOImpl implements VoitureDAO {
@PersistenceContext(name = "JPADD")
EntityManager em;

@Override
public void save(Voiture voiture) {
    em.persist(voiture);
}
}
```

the implementation 
    package com.DAO.Impl;

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.DAO.PersonneDAO;
import com.domain.Personne;

@Stateless
public class PersonneDAOImpl implements PersonneDAO {
@PersistenceContext(name = "JPADD")
EntityManager em;

@Override
public String sayhello() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "helllllllllllllllllo";
}

@Override
public void save(Personne personne) {
    em.persist(personne);
}
}
```

this is the test

```
package test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.DAO.PersonneDAO;
import com.domain.Personne;
import com.domain.Voiture;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Context intialcontext;
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    try {
        intialcontext = new InitialContext(properties);
        PersonneDAO dao = (PersonneDAO) intialcontext
                .lookup("ejb:/projetweb/PersonneDAOImpl!com.DAO.PersonneDAO");
        // /----------------------------objet voiture-------------
        Voiture voiture = new Voiture("216");
        Set<Voiture> voitures = new HashSet<Voiture>();
        voitures.add(voiture);
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        Personne personne = new Personne("slatnia");
        personne.setVoitures(voitures);
        dao.save(personne);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

}
```

and this is my jboss-ejb-client.properties

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost   
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

Comment: can you please add your error scenario as well?

Comment: @UNNI there are no errors generated in my console there is only one warning WARN: Unsupported message received with header 0xffffffff

Answer (score 0):

Try add following attributes to the @OneToMany annotation

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: @UNNI 
there are no errors generated in my console there is only one warning 
WARN: Unsupported message received with header 0xffffffff

Answer (score 0):

You should add `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` in the `@OneToMany`

**CascadeType.PERSIST**

> When persisting an entity, also persist the entities held in this
>   field. We suggest liberal application of this cascade rule, because if
>   the EntityManager finds a field that references a new entity during
>   flush, and the field does not use CascadeType.PERSIST, it is an error.

example:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Voiture> voitures;
```

Javadoc for [CascadeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) and other doc at [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.1/apache-openjpa-1.0.1/docs/manual/jpa_overview_meta_field.html#jpa_overview_meta_cascade).

Comment: i try 
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Voiture> voitures;

but it don't work